# How to add 'pass parameter' to custom AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, custom-attributes

I want to secure controller action so that only users with role "Admin" can get in.
I don't use Role/Membership provider at all everything is custom.
I made this so far:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);            
        if (!isAuthorized)
            return false;

        string username = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;

        UserRepository repo = new UserRepository();

        return repo.IsUserInRole(username, "Admin");
    }
}
```

Notice that I hardcoded "Admin" here.
I want that this be dynamic.
This work now:

```
[CustomAuthorize]
        public ActionResult RestrictedArea()...
```

But I want something like this:

```
[CustomAuthorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        public ActionResult RestrictedArea()
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`AuthorizeAttribute` already has `Roles` property which can be used for this purpose:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);            
        if (!isAuthorized)
        {
            return false;
        }

        string username = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;

        UserRepository repo = new UserRepository();

        return repo.IsUserInRole(username, this.Roles);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting `this.Roles` value as `null`

Comment: Did you pass value to `Roles` variable `[CustomAuthorize(Roles="admin")]`?

Comment: Unfortunately, without your code I cannot help you. I can, however give you advice. Firstly try step-by-step debugging (including breakpoint on `Roles` setter, which will require provding custom `set` method, not the automatical which we have here) and trying to reporduce it in a new (minimal) project.

Comment: AuthorizeAttribute already has a property 'Roles'.  remove the public string Roles { get; set; } and leave the rest as it is